# Is There a Winapi way to Move a File to The Recycling Bin?

Tags: c++, winapi, command-line

I've looking into a lot of different methods, but most of them require adding a file to System32, while I'm looking for a line that would allow you to move something to the recycle bin without anything being added to a computer, because I want something that would work on all Windows computers immediately. Rest assured that the deletion will not delete any major files and will ask for confirmation. I am thinking of using system("") in C++ to run the line.

Answer (score 15):

See [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx) with `FOF_ALLOWUNDO`.

Comment: Important caveat: "If pFrom is set to a file name without a full path, deleting the file with FO_DELETE does not move it to the Recycle Bin, even if the FOF_ALLOWUNDO flag is set. You must provide a full path to delete the file to the Recycle Bin."

Comment: From the link: "This function has been replaced in Windows Vista by [IFileOperation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775771.aspx)."

Comment: As for me, I can't see any reason for using IFileOperation instead of the SHFileOperation function (except Microsoft's recommendations) because it does not provide new features (it looks like currently, it is just a wrapper around SHFileOperation) but brings a headake for those who write in C++/MFC because it requires IShellItem instances instead of just paths.

Comment: I expected IFileOperation in comparison to SHFileOperation may provide more details about the execution process, but no. For example, if the operation was canceled, both IFileOperation and SHFileOperation can't provide info on which entries were processed and which were canceled. The same for other processing errors.

Comment: @Mar: I haven't tried it but `IFileOperation::Advise(IFileOperationProgressSink*, ...)` seems to let you figure out which entries were processed and which weren't?

Comment: @Mehrdad: thank you, my fault - I have overlooked this method and intended to try the same via IOperationsProgressDialog. Now I will try the Advise/IFileOperationProgressSink and will report the results.

Comment: @Mar: Yeah no worries, the name `Advice` isn't exactly enlightening. I only randomly happened to see it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of Recycle-Bin commandline tools mentioned here on alt.comp[1] (It even includes a fully automatic daemon that translates any file delete into 'move-to-recycle-bin')

The most popular seems to be Recycle from [CmdUtils by Maddog](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/), which is *free* and [*open source* (GPL)](http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/cmdutils.zip).

[1] [Command line delete to recycle bin?](http://groups.google.com/group/alt.comp.freeware/browse_thread/thread/6b84f8b130d7bf45/11b6b1d9aa13b1a3)

Comment: to see `SHFileOperation` in action, look at the end of CmdUtils-Source.zip\recycle\Recycle.c within http://www.maddogsw.com/cmdutils/cmdutils.zip